# Python | How to call a function multiple times with different args at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

lets say we have a function 'ios' that takes three args a,b,c which takes about 25 seconds to execute all of the satements

```
import threading
import time

def ios(a,b,c):
    time.sleep(25)
    print(a,b,c)

def run(a,b,c):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=ios, args=[a,b,c])
    t1.start()
    return 'please wait ...'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        #On listening state
        print('Enter values:')
        a,b,c = input()
        ack_message = run(a, b, c)
        print(ack_message)
```

Expected output: which I'm getting right in this example

```
Enter values:
123
please wait ...
Enter values:
456
please wait ...
Enter values:
567
please wait ...
Enter values:
1 2 3
4 5 6
5 6 7
```

Now when another func call to 'ios' takes place while it's running, The args passed are overwritten with new values which in-turn changes the output and I do not want that to happen.

I would like to get the output of the first request and then it has to move on with the next func call - Is there a way we could do this?
Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Why would a call to *ios* change the parameters? They are local to the function, so each invocation has different parameters. Is this a problem you are ACTUALLY seeing, or something you THINK will happen?

Comment: If the threaded calls to the actual function are interfering with each other, then the function must be using some global (or otherwise shared) state.  Either encapsulate that state in a class (and give each call its own instance of that class), or use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Your last paragraph seems to imply that you want function calls to execute sequentially. If so, why are you using threading?

Comment: Why do you think you're seeing this 'override' behavior? Could you please attach code that demonstrates that?

Comment: I do not see a problem here. Can you show code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mkam
I think so because during subsequent func calls to ios, some part of data is carried forward and some part of it gets altered, at-least that's how I see in the final output.
In other words - what I'm looking for is,
The next func call to ios should either HOLD until the first func call finishes or it would be better to have these executed parallel without interfering with the inputs/args.

Please advise if I need to look out for some other approach  (Not threading)
Note:- I would want the return statement ('Please wait...) as an ack message as soon the user calls func ios

Comment: @jasonharper, How would I go about encapsulating that state in a class? could you please share some ref doc? thanks

Comment: The example you give works fine, as you yourself said. It would be more helpful if you can post an example which does NOT work fine - at least we can see the problem for ourselves.